# Stratos 1.6.0 - Messaging between Storage Server and Data Service Service

Tags: wso2

I am configuring Stratos 1.6.0 and trying get the following scenario working.

1. Create a database in Storage Server
2. Create a user in Storage Server
3. Assign the user to the database
4. Generate datasource for the user/database combination in the Storage Server
5. Create DataService in Data Service Server and use the data source above

From what I can see in the code... when one creates a datasource in a Carbon application, the org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository will notify the member's in the cluster of the new DataSource. These members will then invalidate the registry cache.

The problem comes is that in the default clustering configuration in Stratos 1.6.0, the Storage Server and the Data Service Server are in different Tribe domains, so messaging using Tribe is not possible between the two types of applications.

How can one get the Data Service Server to update its datasource configuration when datasources are created in the Storage Server?

Answer (score 0):

What you've mentioned in your query itself is exactly what's expected from providing the option to create a datasource via WSO2 Storage Server. However, there are certain technical complexities associated with sharing datasources across nodes/clusters of different Carbon products (other than the type of Carbon product in which the datasources are created) and we're currently in the middle of attending to them. Therefore, all considered, a better way to integrate SS with DSS would be, first create your database/database user in WSO2 SS, then create datasources with that information (connection strings, user credentials, etc) in WSO2 DSS and consume them.

Regards,
Prabath

P.S. You can refer http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.in/2013/04/relational-storage-solution-using-wso2.html which provides you with a comprehensive guide for creating databases/database users/privilege templates.